# Boot shortcut into a specific partition

Tags: boot, partitioning, keyboard-shortcuts, multi-boot

I have a dual boot setup which  works just fine

Both partitions run windows 10

By default the main partition a is loaded on boot . I can boot into partition b by pressing shift + restart  ( or through  "advanced startup options" ) , which brings a menu to choose from after rebooting .

I would like to have a shortcut, which will boot from partition a,  and load partition b *automatically* after boot, without going through a menu.  Possibly via a cmd command ,  or any  other way .

Searched the web extensively ,  surprised to not find a solution

Thanks for any advice

Comment: Could you add some screen shot of the manual way which you complete with success which you want to find a shorter way or a method to simplify or automate any related steps of that process without going through all the UIs? Just add some screen shots, I'd be surprised if command line equivalent something is available to automate any of that for you.

Comment: Just a guesswork but what if you use bcdedit.exe to change the boot order from a to b being now the first in list and restart the PC? Or change default from a to b or b to a as required. If feasible a .BAT file can be created on both OSs doing this task of changing boot order or default OS and restarting PC?

Comment: It's unclear whether the two installations are sharing one Windows Boot Manager. If they are, essentially you'll need to make it otherwise (with bcdboot et. al.), then you can use a bootloader like grub to choose which to boot.

Comment: @patkim /bootsequence looks great in that it is only for the next boot. If it was possible to /default  this way,  seems  like the  wanted solution

Answer (score 1):

This is a tentative solution. Request OP to confirm if this is how their system is  or provide further clarification. Accordingly I will retain or delete this answer.

For a case like two Windows 10s on two partitions on same physical disk, sharing BCD, I have tested and simulated following in a VM and it worked. Windows 10 booted in UEFI mode.

Let’s call them A & B.

By default, a boot menu with timeout is presented and it boots into A.

[image]

When in A run CMD as admin and run the following BCDEDIT command

```
bcdedit.exe /enum /v
```

This will show both Boot entries with respective GUIDs (Identifier). Note the GUIDs of A & B. On C: is default one i.e. A and other is B

[image]

In my case it is

```
PARTITION-A {cbfd7d64-7716-11ed-bd95-e6c5a4548684}
PARTITION-B {cbfd7d68-7716-11ed-bd95-e6c5a4548684}
```

Your GUIDs would be different, so make a note of them. We need them in subsequent BCDEDIT commands.

When booted into A, create a BAT file say boot-B.BAT on desktop with following code in it.

```
@echo off
bcdedit.exe /default {cbfd7d68-7716-11ed-bd95-e6c5a4548684}
bcdedit.exe /timeout 0
shutdown -r -t 1
exit
```

Run it as admin. This will

- Change default OS to B as per its GUID. **You will need to replace GUID
  with yours here**.
- Set timeout to 0, no more boot menu
- Restart Windows (Ideally make sure you don't have any apps running else they might pause or prevent shutdown operation)

This will now automatically boot into B and will remain in B until you change it.
So in B create a similar BAT file but set the default to A

```
@edcho off
bcdedit.exe /default  {cbfd7d64-7716-11ed-bd95-e6c5a4548684}
bcdedit.exe /timeout 0
shutdown -r -t 1
exit
```

Anytime you want to get back the boot menu just run the command

```
bcdedit.exe /timeout 10
```

from elevated command prompt. This will set 10 second timeout and menu will be presented, just in case.

Note that BCD holds critical data for proper booting. A wrong bcdedit command may result into a non-bootable system. So better have backups before you undertake this activity.

Answer (score 0):

A shortcut  needs an operating system, so what you want to do is not practical in any way.

You need to boot the partition in the ordinary way like a boot loader.